# Persistent state between requests in Python gRPC server?

Tags: python, grpc

In the Python implementation of gRPC servers, is it possible to maintain some persistent per-thread state between requests? (looks like all examples use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, but I haven't found much documentation on what the actual server model is)

This would be for things with a non-negligible setup cost that I'd want to avoid doing on every RPC call, but which I can't rely on being thread-safe. E.g. DB connections, setting up an in-memory cache, etc.

Comment: What problem are you having using the standard library's `threading.local` for per-thread state?

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle no problems with using that, was just interested whether the server provided any such capabilities, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in the sense of "nothing is stopping you from doing it" but gRPC Python doesn't provide specific utilities to assist with per-thread state.